# node.js Error: connect ECONNREFUSED; response from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost, node.js-connect

I have a problem with this little program:

```node
var http = require("http");
var request = http.request({
    hostname: "localhost",
    port: 8000,
    path: "/",
    method: "GET"
}, function(response) {
    var statusCode = response.statusCode;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var statusLine = "HTTP/" + response.httpVersion + " " +statusCode + " " + http.STATUS_CODES[statusCode];
    console.log(statusLine);
    for (header in headers) {
        console.log(header + ": " + headers[header]);
    }
    console.log();
    response.setEncoding("utf8");
    response.on("data", function(data) {
        process.stdout.write(data);
    });
    response.on("end", function() {
        console.log();
    });
});
```

The result in console is this:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

I do not understand why this happens.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the code?

Comment: That happens because it could not connect to the endpoint - in this case `http://localhost:8000` is not reachable

Comment: Are you supposed to have something running on localhost:8000? Because it doesn't look like you do right now.

Comment: trying with other programs is reached. Port 8000 is free

Comment: @MarcoGhieri what do you mean by _free_? There's nothing listening on it? That would explain the error.

Comment: I had the same problem, not sure why I couldn't get a response from the server. The answer is in "Promise"

For my situation, 

 1. I checked from cli that node is listening on my port
 2. I was able to use curl to make a request to it and it was all good.
 3. The problem was when I use the "request" module, it ran it before the server could get back to me, so I downloaded 'request-promise' and that solved the problem. This is not an answer but for those who have been searching, you can see if the async, sync thing is your hint.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and the reason is that my node program is calling one rest api. I get this error if that rest api is not accessible. Can someone tell me how to handle that exception, because it crashes my node server which i want to avoid.

Comment: I get the same when using mysql2 or mysqljs node library

Comment: I was running node 17 (on a M1 Mac) and I removed it via `brew uninstall node` and then install node 16 with `brew install node@16`. Worked a treat. I _may_ have had to `brew link --force node@16` but I can't remember right now.

Answer (score 48):

From your code, It looks like your file contains code that makes get request to localhost (127.0.0.1:8000).

The problem might be you have not created server on your local machine which listens to port 8000.

For that you have to set up server on localhost which can serve your request.

1. Create server.js

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.send('Hello World!'); // This will serve your request to '/'.
   });

   app.listen(8000, function () {
     console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!');
    });
   ```
2. Run server.js : node server.js
3. Run file that contains code to make request.

Comment: NB. As as a general rule processes running without root privileges cannot bind to ports below 1024.

Comment: @RoccoMusolino answer above worked for me. After fighting with this error for a whole day on an iMac, `sudo` did the trick! I wonder where node or iOS`(putting this here for web crawler)` was getting `127.0.0.1:80` Even with all proxy settings disabled, I still got this error

Answer (score 18):

Please use [::1] instead of localhost, and make sure that the port is correct, and put the port inside the link.

```
const request = require('request');

   let json = {
        "id": id,
        "filename": filename
    };
    let options = {
        uri: "http://[::1]:8000" + constants.PATH_TO_API,
        // port:443,
        method: 'POST',
        json: json
    };
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.error("httpRequests : error " + error);
        }
        if (response) {
            let statusCode = response.status_code;
            if (callback) {
                callback(body);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain why someone should do it this way?

Comment: this works for me too. What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: Also worked for me. Once I added the `port` to the `options` the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with `redis-server`, you can install that like this!

> `sudo apt-get install redis-server`

after that see the port and change it!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my mac, but in my case, the problem was that I did not run the database (sudo mongod) before; the problem was solved when I first ran the mondo sudod on the console and, once it was done, on another console, the connection to the server ...

Answer (score 0):

i ran the local mysql database, but not in administrator mode, which threw this error

Answer (score 0):

If you have stopped the mongod.exe service from the task manager, you need to restart the service. In my case I stopped the service from task manager and on restart it doesn't automatically started.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following command in the node project:

```
npm install
```

Its worked for me.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question that's being asked.

Comment: fair point @daveyvdweide. but it solved my issue anyway. so thanks manikandan!

Comment: man. i pulled my hair for this. it didn't come to my mind to update deps after a major update and i checkedout to `master` and it needed update.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because my AdonisJS server was not running before I ran the test. Running the server first fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on postman ,when try to connect docker container ,just double check the port your server is running and the endpoint (port you are tring to access),I changed the port it worked for me

Answer (score -6):

use a proxy property in your code it should work just fine

```
const https = require('https');
const request = require('request');

request({
    'url':'https://teamtreehouse.com/chalkers.json',
    'proxy':'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx'
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = body;
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
);
```